# How to make the slot associate with QTimer::timeout can be interrupted by any other signal processor(higher priority) and then resume?

Tags: qt, network-programming, simulation, wifi

To simplify the question, let's say that i have a `QTimer`, which will trigger its timeout event every 3000ms.

```
QTimer timer;

QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&](){
    // do sth(rely on a public data structure)
}); 

timer.start(3000);
```

The operation inside the lambda connected to the `timeout` event is relied on a public data structure.

And the application hold an `QUdpSocket`, and connect the `readyRead` signal with a slot function.

```
QUdpSocket socket;
socket.bind(45454, QUdpSocket::ReuseAddressHint);

QObject::connect(&socket, &QUdpSocket::readyRead, [&](){
    //manipulate the public data structure
}
```

As you can see, the lambda connected to the `readyRead` signal manipulate the public data structure that the first lambda rely on.

So my question is, i want the function that connectted to the `readyRead` signal has the highest "priority", that is, even in the Qt's event loop are dealing with the `timeout` slot now, it can be interrupted and start the `readyRead` slot immediately, then after it finish, resume the `timeout` slot function. Is there any way to do so?

(My homework is to simulate the IEEE802.11 exposed/hidden node problem, it requires that i have to constantly listen the channel before/during sending a packet.)

(Is explicitly call `QCoreApplication::processEvent` will help?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the IEEE802.11 exposed/hidden node problem, however i don't think you can "interrupt" your code as you're describing.

One possible way to handle with this would be running the code for the readyRead and the timeout slots on different threads and then use some kind of synchronisation mechanism (QMutex comes to mind) to access the public data (and get its state).

i.e.

1. add some kind of uniqueid to identify the public_data current status
2. timeout_slot will acquire a lock, read the public data in a local copy and release the lock, then continue to manipulate local structure and finally before release would acquire lock again and check that the uniqueid has not been changed, if so commit your work, otherwise you'd have to start over.
3. readyRead_slot would acquire the lock, update the uniqueid and then continue working

Comment: Can i shared a global variable ```QMutex``` on different threads that run different event loop?

Comment: Indeed, mutexes have to be shared by threads that need to use them :)